# real proxy implementation issue when trying to break the pipeline in c#

Tags: c#, proxy, pipeline, realproxy

AuthenticationProxy.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies;
using System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Threading;

namespace ProxyWithAOP
{
public class AuthenticationProxy<T> : RealProxy
{
    private readonly T _decorated;
    public AuthenticationProxy(T decorated)
      : base(typeof(T))
    {
        _decorated = decorated;
    }

    private void Log(string msg, object arg = null)
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
        Console.WriteLine(msg, arg);
        Console.ResetColor();
    }

    public override IMessage Invoke(IMessage msg)
    {
        var methodCall = msg as IMethodCallMessage;
        var methodInfo = methodCall.MethodBase as MethodInfo;

        if (Thread.CurrentPrincipal.IsInRole("ADMIN"))
        {
            try
            {
                Log("User authenticated - You can execute '{0}' ", methodCall.MethodName);

                var result = methodInfo.Invoke(_decorated, methodCall.InArgs);

                return new ReturnMessage(result, null, 0, methodCall.LogicalCallContext, methodCall);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Log(string.Format("User authenticated - Exception {0} executing '{1}'", e), methodCall.MethodName);

                return new ReturnMessage(e, methodCall);
            }
        }

        Log("User not authenticated - You can't execute '{0}' ", methodCall.MethodName);

        return new ReturnMessage(-1, null, 0, methodCall.LogicalCallContext, methodCall);
    }
}
}
```

DynamicProxy.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies;
using System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ProxyWithAOP
{
class DynamicProxy<T> : RealProxy
{
    private readonly T _decorated;

    public DynamicProxy(T decorated)
      : base(typeof(T))
    {
        _decorated = decorated;
    }

    private void Log(string msg, object arg = null)
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
        Console.WriteLine(msg, arg);
        Console.ResetColor();
    }

    public override IMessage Invoke(IMessage msg)
    {
        var methodCall = msg as IMethodCallMessage;
        var methodInfo = methodCall.MethodBase as MethodInfo;

        Log("In Dynamic Proxy - Before executing '{0}'", methodCall.MethodName);

        try
        {
            var result = methodInfo.Invoke(_decorated, methodCall.InArgs);

            Log("In Dynamic Proxy - After executing '{0}' ", methodCall.MethodName);

            return new ReturnMessage(result, null, 0, methodCall.LogicalCallContext, methodCall);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log(string.Format("In Dynamic Proxy- Exception {0} executing '{1}'", e), methodCall.MethodName);

            return new ReturnMessage(e, methodCall);
        }
    }
}
}
```

I have declared two methods as -`int GetCustomer(T entity);` and `double GetBalance(T entity);`

Added methods in pipeline as

```
var decorated = TraceProxy<ICustomerOperations>.Create(new CustomerOperations());
decorated = AuthenticationProxy<ICustomerOperations>.Create(decorated);
```

now I am calling my customer methods using decorator as

```
decorated.GetCustomer(1);
decorated.GetBalance(1);
```

above methods have distinct return type as int and string.
When user is not authenticated in AuthenticationProxy class, then it returns object as `return new ReturnMessage(-1, null, 0, methodCall.LogicalCallContext, methodCall);`(Authentication.cs invoke method)

`decorated.GetCustomer(1);` call has been successful as return type match as `int`. However `decorated.GetBalance(1);` is throwing `InvalidCastException` exception as its excepting `double` return type value.

So how to resolve this problem? I want to make it generic so that there should not be return type issue.

Comment: In AuthenticationProxy, when user is not authenticated, now I am throwing authentication exception instead of ReturnMessage. its working in this case.